# Can I use LINQ to create a new list of objects from an existing list

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a list of invoices that have both start and end dates. Can I use LINQ to get all the start and end dates from the invoice list and put them into a new list of type `Period`:

```
Period(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {};
```

I can do this with a `foreach` as shown below but wanted to know if there was a better way to do this with LINQ.

```
foreach(Invoice invoice in invoices)
{
    periods.Add(new Period(invoice.StartDate, invoice.EndDate));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a new periods list:

```
List<Period> periods = invoices.Select(i => new Period(i.StartDate, i.EndDate)).ToList();
```

If you want to attach the invoice items to a existing periods list:

```
periods.AddRange(invoices.Select(i => new Period(i.StartDate, i.EndDate)));
```